# Numpy array - IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have reviewed threads for this particular subject, but none of the solutions are applicable to my situation and I need help with this, please. I am trying to prep my data for training using neural language model. My data has already been pre-processed and stored in text file. The sample data is as follows: ["restaurant", "paris", "district", "gunman", "held", "hostage"...] and the array shape  is (10848135,), as per array shape attribute. However I get an index error message when I try to slice the data with statement `X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]`

The code is as follows:

```
def encode_words(self, dataset):
        data = dataset.split('\n')
        tokenizer = Tokenizer()
        tokenizer.fit_on_texts(dataset)
        sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(dataset)
        vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
        sequences = array(sequences)
        X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]
        y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
        seq_length = X.shape[1]
        return X, y, vocab_size, seq_length, tokenizer
```

I understand what the error is, but don't know how to fix this. Please I need assistance to get the code working. Below is the full error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/processor.py", line 15, in <module>
    X,y,vocab_size,seq_length,tokenizer = emb.encode_words(seq_data)

  File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/WordEmbedding.py", line 67, in encode_words
    X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: It looks like your array `sequences` only has a single axis. You'll need to reshape it to have two axes.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `sequences`?

Comment: @hpaulj, sequences is an object dtype

Comment: You need to examine `sequences` in more detail.  1d object dtype is probably an array of lists or arrays - and those lists vary in size.  Until you understand the exact nature of that array, you can't reshape or slice in a meaningful way.

Comment: @hpaulj, I've manged to reshape and sliced **sequences** with (2, 104309) as the  output shape -  although I'm not sure if the new shape and slice are correct.  However this line of code ``` y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size) ``` throws the following error message:                                                    ```File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py", line 25, in to_categorical
    y = np.array(y, dtype='int')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. ```   Pls any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: Look at the contents of `y`!  You can only make an integer dtype array if it contains numbers or strings that represent numbers.  Given your shape issues, I suspect `y` is an object dtype array with a mix of elements, such as lists or other arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1-d array and is trying to slice in two dimensions. Thats why you are getting this error.

Your array shape is (10848135,), this means that you have only 1 dimension. If you are expecting to have a second dimension from where you need to extract your `y` array, you need to review your file because it has 1d array. Therefore, you can't access like this.

Answer (score 0):

The array you have is 1D and your are trying to access it as 2D.
check why is is 1D in the first place if you expecting a 2D.